# Use X-FD-HealthProbe with Application Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway

I have an App Service behind an Application Gateway.

I would like to use the X-FD-HealthProbe header filter setting in my AppService so that I restrict traffic to my AppService to only the HealthProbes of my AppGateway.

How can I find my HealthProbe ID in Application Gateway? I can't find any documentation on this.

Comment: Please refer [Create probe for Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-create-probe-portal#create-probe-for-application-gateway-v2-sku)  and [Application Gateway health monitoring overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-probe-overview#custom-health-probe-settings)

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not see anything related to the Probe ID in this documentation.

Comment: Did you figure it out @2d1b?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following az cli to retrieve the probe ID:

```
az network application-gateway probe show --gateway-name <gatewayName> --resource-group <gatewayRG> --name <nameOfProbe>
```

Comment: "Each health probe must have a length of at most 64 characters.". the `id` seems to be too long. the `name` does not work.